# Other website tracking

Tags: html, html5-history, tabbed-browsing

I am trying to build a website that will have promotional offers and I would like to ask the specialists in here if what I want is possible.
Let's call my site A
Another site - C

A visitor goes to website C then comes to website A. Is it possible for me to know that he visited website C before coming to my website ( presuming ofcourse he hasn't used a tool like ccleaner to empty his browsing history ). Knowing this I could display a message like. Our price is 5% lower than site C.
Also another limited way would be to read the tab of the browser? If user has site C and site A open in the same time, in the same browser I could view that he visits both in the same time?
I am open to all solutions that would allow me to do this. Initially I thought it's possible through local storage in html5 but upon reading I start to think it's not. However I just started studying and will look further.

Comment: Due to obvious security reasons this is possible only in special cases like when the user clicks a link on C that leads directly to A, or if C has installed a script that you control.

Comment: The only way to do this is embedding code in the pages on website C.
Or you could exploit bugs, but that's something I strongly discourage.

Comment: The internet would be a horrible place if it were possible that code in a destination  websites were allowed to do this sort of thing. The spam and marketing would be endless. Luckily this is prevented unless both sites agree to share code or pass in tracking tokens on links and the like. I also doubt that if this capability existed that the destination site would  honour the "don't track" preferences of the user browser. - why would they ? - Thank goodness you can't do it.

Comment: thanks, no I wasn't thinking of exploits, I thought it was a legit way or reading opened browser tabs ( just their title, name ).